# Mysterious pickle error while profiling a multi-process Python script

Tags: python, parallel-processing, profiling

I"m using the `multiprocessing` module, and I'm using `UpdateMessage` objects (my own class), sent through `multiprocessing.Queue` objects, to communicate between processes. Here's the class:

```
class UpdateMessage:
    def __init__(self, arrayref, rowslice, colslice, newval):
        self.arrayref = arrayref
        self.rowslice = rowslice
        self.colslice = colslice
        self.newval = newval
    def do_update(self):
        if self.arrayref == 'uL':
            arr = uL
        elif self.arrayref == 'uR':
            arr = uR
        else:
            raise Exception('UpdateMessage.arrayref neither uL nor uR')
        arr[self.rowslice, self.colslice] = self.newval
```

When I run the script, it works perfectly fine. However, when I run it with either `cProfile` or `profile`, it gives the following error:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.UpdateMessage'>: attribute lookup __main__.UpdateMessage failed
```

It seems to be trying to pickle the class, but I can't see why this is happening. My code doesn't do this, and it works just fine without it, so it's probably the `multiprocessing` module. But why would it need to pickle `UpdateMessage`, and how can I fix the error?

EDIT: here's part of the code that's sending the `UpdateMessage` (multiple parts of the script do this, but all in the same way):

```
msg = UpdateMessage(uLref, refer[0] + marker[0] - 2,
                    slice(uL.shape[1]), ustar.copy())
queue.put(msg)
```

The traceback isn't very helpful:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 272, in _feed
    send(obj)
```

Comment: The reason `UpdateMessage` is getting pickled is that the interprocess communication path is just a byte stream, so class instances need to be serialized to be sent to another process. I don't know why `profile` interferes with that, though.

Comment: I have got a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41892297/1878788
This could be related to the following bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue9914

Answer (score 5):

I do not know how your processes look like but:

```
'__main__.UpdateMessage'
```

refers to UpdateMessage in the launched module.

When another process is started not with the Module of the class `UpdateMessage`, UpdateMessage will not be available.

you have to import that module that includes UpdateMessage so
`UpdateMessage.__module__ is not '__main__'`.

Then Pickle can find UpdateMessage also in other programs.

I recommend the `__main__.py` to look like this:

```
import UpdateMessage_module

UpdateMessage_module.main()
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and solved it by defining the class to be pickled in its own file.

Comment: Your advice worked for me for functions that were attributes of a class that had to be pickled. I had errors like `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function count_annot at 0x7fabb38c3c80>: attribute lookup count_annot on __main__ failed`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the pickling attempt on your class is happening before your class is sent to another process.  The easiest solution is probably just to implement the pickle-protocol explicitly on your class...